# Spectral analysis of spectrum analyzer

Tags: power, signal, fourier, spectrum-analyzer, power-measurement

Using measures from a spectral analyzer, I am a bit confused on how to properly compare the power of each spectral line with the fourier coefficients (Parseval).

Take this signal:
[image]

Take its spectrum:
[image]

My experience with spectrum analyzers being limited, I attempt to compare what I expect with what I read.

The Fourier series coefficients of the ramp signal are:
$$
D_n = \frac{-jA_{pk}(-1)^n}{\pi n}
$$

So I expect a single spectral line on the spectrum analyzer to have power:
$$
P_n = 2 \cdot |D_n|^2
$$
Where the factor 2 is due to the signal being real (taking into account both contributions at -f and f).

And so, for the first spectral line (at n = 1), I'd expect to have:
$$
P_n = 2 \cdot \left( \frac{0.1 \cdot (-1)}{\pi} \right)^2 \approx 2.02642 \cdot 10^{-3} W
$$

Now, converting the spectrum analyzer's dBm to watts:
$$
P_{experimental} = 10^{(P_{dBm} - 30)/10} = 10^{((-13.85) - 30)/10} = \approx 4.12098 \cdot 10^{-5} W
$$

It seems I have a somewhat huge error on this measure. However, it seems the spectrum measures are not entirely uncorrelated with the Fourier series powers, in the sense that the factors between the measures and the actual powers calculated using Fourier series seem constant. It seems to be a simple scaling error.

Maybe I miss something, and I wondered if anybody would maybe see something on the instruments captures I don't see.

Comment: P=U*I, you have just U, what power are talking about?

Comment: The spectral power? On the spectrum analyzer? The PSD?

Comment: In your equations, I am missing a transformation  of  spectral power [dB]  to electrical power [W]

Comment: Yes the impedance of both the signal generator and the spectrum analyzer are 50 Ohm. No external attenuator was used. For the DC block, I don't know much about it, I don't doubt its quality though, in order words for the frequencies I was using it with, there shouldn't be any issues. I *think* it's something trivial like a setting on the spectral analyzer of something... (who knows). Or a calculation error? Anyway, I understand it's hard to guess, just wondering if the calculations are even correct in the first place, assuming the measures are correct.

Comment: I converted from dBm simply using these equations : https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/power/dBm_to_Watt.html

Comment: I see the notation **Att: 20.00 dB** on your spectrum analyzer display, which could account for the order-of-magnitude error. The remaining factor of roughly 2 could be the fact that you used the **Current** peak-to-peak value of the amplitude rather than the **Mean** value, which is closer to what the spectrum analyzer sees. You seem to have a lot of AM on this signal that we can't see in the time-domain display.

Comment: Erm actually I'm wrong. An external attenuator was on the BNC of the spectrum analyzer. So this means the attenuator setting is in fact okay...

Answer (score 0):

So here are a few hints;

If you account for the 20 dB attenuation, you get a number that is much closer to your estimate, but off by a factor of 2.

(The picture of your spectrum analyzer says "Att: 20 dB" on the top.)

To resolve that factor of 2, you could try using the mean amplitude instead of the max amplitude in your estimation of the power at the first peak.